# Where can I find data that shows USAID development assistance in the Congo?

Tags: usaidopen

Please show me where the data information is on the website.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and define *USAID development assistance*. **What data do you want** (money, people, food, building materials, vehicles, ...) **and with what resolution over time and place?**.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you were looking for ?
https://www.usaid.gov/democratic-republic-congo

Answer (score 2):

The [Foreign Assistance Dashboard](http://beta.foreignassistance.gov/) (FAD) has downloadable financial information from several U.S. Government agencies.

There are several tools available from [Economic Analysis and Data Services](https://eads.usaid.gov/) (EADS) on the usaid.gov website.